# Cannot run Jupyter notebook directly in the terminal on Mac

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to run jupyter notebook on my mac using `jupyter notebook` in the terminal, but if I run this code, it gives me an error:

```
vlan-2625-10-16-106-253:~ brandon$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook'
```

**But if I use `/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -m jupyter notebook`, then it works.**

I know maybe it's because I have several versions of python on my computer, or it's because the path of jupyter is incorrect, but I don't know how to deal with it.

```
vlan-2625-10-16-106-253:~ brandon$ which jupyter
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
vlan-2625-10-16-106-253:~ brandon$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

If I tried to uninstall jupyter by `brew uninstall jupyter` or `pip3 uninstall jupyter` and then `pip3 install jupyter`, it still doesn't work.

If I install jupyter again, it shows:

```
vlan-2625-10-16-106-253:~ brandon$ pip3 install jupyter
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: notebook in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter) (6.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter) (5.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter) (5.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter) (6.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter) (7.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (6.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=5.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (7.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.2 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter) (6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (49.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jedi>=0.10->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pexpect>4.3->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0->ipython>=5.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.1.0->ipykernel->jupyter) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: widgetsnbextension~=3.5.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (3.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat>=4.2.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (5.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (4.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (3.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent>=0.14.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.4.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.3 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash>=1.5.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (22.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: prometheus-client in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (0.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: argon2-cffi in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (20.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter-client->ipykernel->jupyter) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from argon2-cffi->notebook->jupyter) (1.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from cffi>=1.0.0->argon2-cffi->notebook->jupyter) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jinja2->notebook->jupyter) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune<2,>=0.8.1 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: testpath in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: defusedxml in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter) (3.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (20.4)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from packaging->bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: qtpy in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (1.9.0)
```

If I want to run .ipynb file in pyCharm, I also receive the same error:
[image]

I think it's the same problem as I cannot directly run `jupyter notebook` in the terminal. This problem has been bothering me a lot and i searched a lot but I still can't figure it out. I wonder if I can change the path of `jupyter` command? It would be helpful if someone can answer this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's in `/usr/local/bin/jupyter`? If it's a script, what's its first line?

Answer (score -1):

you can check if python.exe is added on path .Environment Variables >>>  System variables >>> path.(This is for windows) but i think there should be sth similar.